# Event Notification Delivery Method - Ebay error - HTTP status code 405

Tags: python, flask, heroku, ebay-api

I have used the following guide - https://developer.ebay.com/marketplace-account-deletion

So I've created a flask based website on python and uploaded in Heroku,

https://ebay-deletion.herokuapp.com/

If you create a query parameter, for the challenge code like so:

https://ebay-deletion.herokuapp.com/?challenge_code=123

It returns a challenge response and doc type (JSON).

I don't understand but why but I get this error below:

Notification delivery failed with HTTP status code 405 from https://ebay-deletion.herokuapp.com. Please ensure that the marketplace account deletion notification endpoint is ready to receive notifications.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Ebay's help page is just so terrible. Their python code examples for hashing in the top link have semi-colons after each line! It's close to completely useless.

Here is the Python Flask code:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    args = request.args
    args_dict = args.to_dict()
    try:
        resp_hash = hashlib.sha256(
            args_dict['challenge_code'].encode() + verification_token.encode() + endpoint.encode())
        resp = {'challengeResponse': resp_hash.hexdigest()}
        return jsonify(resp), 200, {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    except KeyError:
        err = {'status_code': 400, 'message': 'no challenge response in params'}
        return jsonify(err), 400, {'content-type': 'application/json'}
```

Comment: "Their python code examples for hashing in the top link have semi-colons after each line! It's close to completely useless."—FWIW, this is actually legal in Python. It's not _necessary_, and it's terrible style, but semi-colons terminating each statement shouldn't cause the code to blow up.

Comment: Have you tried `strip()`ing all three of your input strings? Trailing newlines are a common problem with this kind of thing, and it isn't clear where `verification_token` and `endpoint` come from.